# How to Implement Interface IPagedCollectionView

Tags: c#, silverlight, interface, paging

I have a `DataPager` and I am doing custom paging. I want to set the `ItemCount` property of the `DataPager` according to the `COUNT` of the total `rows` returned. But I found out that `ItemCount` is a `read-only` property. How can I `set` it? any way out?

The `IPagedCollectionView` Interface that contains the `ItemCount` property

```
public int ItemCount
{
   get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
public int TotalItemCount
{
   get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because logic that calculate (total) count should be encapsulated inside the class

```
public int ItemCount
{
   get { return YOURCALCULATIONMETHOD(); }
}
```

Comment: if you have only "get", that mean that you can use this property only for "getting" purpose, not for "setting".

Comment: So I can never set its value any way?

Answer (score 0):

There is one way but I don't sure You want to do this like this.

I am not good in Silverlight but theoretically You need to create class which inherit from `IPagedCollectionView`

```
public class MyPagedCollectionView : IPagedCollectionView 
{
 public int ItemCount
 {
    get { return this.GetItemCount(); }
 }
 public int TotalItemCount
 {
    get {  return this.GetTotalItemCount(); }
 }

 private int GetTotalItemCount()
 {
     //  Implement the method
 }

 private int GetItemCount()
 {
  //  Implement the method
 }

}
```

Comment: on line `get { this.GetItemCount(); }` there is an error `not all code paths return a value`

Comment: Yes error is obvious, You need to  implement this methods. Now this methods is empty

Comment: Did You  implement all 2 methods?

Comment: Yes implemented both of them

Comment: Sorry I update my answer. Add `return` stetment to gets metods

Comment: I already used the return statement. Code compiles but it doesnot set the `ItemCount` property even do I m passing `int` value of 20 from the method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101980/discussion-between-goodeinstein-and-huma-ali).